# how to check whether the remote machine is pingable in perl

Tags: perl

I need to do check whether the remote machine is pinging so that i can do ssh to that machine and execute commands over there. how to do this check in perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Net::Ping`](http://p3rl.org/Net::Ping), but this is a dumb way to go about it. If you want to connect with SSH, just do it, and handle the failure if you cannot.

If a network interface responds to ping, this is no guarantee that SSH works. Conversely, SSH can work and ping is blocked.

Comment: hmm you are correct. But I just wanted to do basic checking before i could process something. thats why. Thanks bro..

Comment: in my program i use expect to do ssh. in that i 've given like
$argument=root@10.2.2.2;
$exp->spawn("ssh $argument") or die "Cannot spawn ssh to ip $ssh_ip_address\n";

But even if it is not able to do ssh it is not printing Cannot spawn ssh to ip $ssh_ip_address. can you please help me why it does not occur?

Comment: [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this different problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast test that a host is listening on a particular port can be done using [IO::Socket::INET](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket::INET)

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $address_tuple = "$ip:$port";
my $test_sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $address_tuple, Timeout  => 0.15);
if ( $test_sock) {
    # Host is up and appears to be listening on that port
    $test_sock->close();
}
else {
    # Host doesn't appear to be listening on that port
}
```